# Create list of key-values from JSON file in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

My data is in json file as shown below:

vmdata.json

```
{
  "VMDetails":
  [
    {
      "name": "Owner1",
      "vms": [ "vm10", "vm11", "vm12", "vm13" ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Owner2",
      "vms": [ "vm20", "vm21", "vm22", "vm23" ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Owner3",
      "vms": [ "vm30", "vm31", "vm32", "vm33" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need this json data converted to list of key-value pairs and later used for tagging the VMs on vcenter.

```
Owner1: vm11
Owner1: vm12
Owner1: vm13
Owner1: vm14
Owner2: vm21
Owner2: vm22
Owner2: vm23
Owner2: vm24
Owner3: vm31
Owner3: vm32
Owner3: vm33
Owner3: vm34
```

I have assigned the content from the data file to variable using :

```
vms_tobe_tagged: "{{ lookup ('file', 'vmtags.json')| from_json}}"
```

I query and get the list of owners using this and it works well:

```
   - set_fact:
        Owner: "{{ vms_tobe_tagged| json_query('OwnerDetails[*].name') }}"

    - name: Test loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ Owner }}"
```

Is it possible to generate the data using this?

```
loop: "{{ ['alice', 'bob'] |product(['clientdb', 'employeedb', 'providerdb'])|list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I need this json data converted to a list of key-value pairs ..."*

```
Owner1: vm11
Owner1: vm12
Owner1: vm13
Owner1: vm14
Owner2: vm21
...
```

> Is it possible to generate the data using 'product' filter?

A: Yes. With the [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) filter it's possible to create a list that comprises all products. The list of the key-value pairs can be created in the next loop. For example the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    owner_list: "{{ owner_list|
                    default([]) +
                    [item.name]|product(item.vms)|list }}"
  loop: "{{ vms_tobe_tagged.VMDetails }}"

- set_fact:
    owner: "{{ owner|
               default([]) +
               [{item.0: item.1}] }}"
  loop: "{{ owner_list }}"

- debug:
    var: owner
```

give

```
"owner": [
    {
        "Owner1": "vm10"
    }, 
    {
        "Owner1": "vm11"
    }, 
    {
        "Owner1": "vm12"
    }, 
    {
        "Owner1": "vm13"
    }, 
    {
        "Owner2": "vm20"
    ...
```

Comment: Cool. This helps!

Comment: This helped me too. I used json_query, with_subelements to iterate. 

```
- set_fact:
        VMOwnerdetails: "{{ vms_tobe_tagged| json_query('VMDetails[*]') }}"

    - name: Verbose updates
      with_subelements:
        - "{{VMOwnerdetails}}"
        - vms
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.name }} :  {{ item.1 }}" 
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. I used json_query, with_subelements to iterate.

```
- set_fact:
        VMOwnerdetails: "{{ vms_tobe_tagged| json_query('VMDetails[*]') }}"

    - name: Verbose updates
      with_subelements:
        - "{{VMOwnerdetails}}"
        - vms
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.name }} :  {{ item.1 }}"
```